# Asking for HDD encryption password when Ubuntu wakes up

Tags: suspend, encryption

Is it possible for Ubuntu to ask for my HDD encryption password everytime after waking up my system?

For example, when I close my laptop screen, it goes to sleep, and after waking it up I'm only be asked to provide my user password, and not my HDD encryption password. I want my HDD to be protected with encryption password when I close my laptop... is it possible?

I'm using the latest Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. When you encrypt a drive, the encryption key is temporarily stored in RAM. When you shut down your computer or put it into hibernation, the RAM is powered down, and the key is lost, meaning you will have to provide it again when you want to continue using the system. When you put the system into sleep mode, the RAM stays powered on and the encryption key stays in memory. The laptop will not ask you for the password again since it already has it.

A sleeping computer is less secure from an encryption security standpoint than a computer that is in hibernation or is powered down. Since the key is still in memory, the only thing protecting the contents of the drive is the code running which tells the computer to refuse access if the login password is not entered. Unlike a computer that is powered down, a sleeping computer does not benefit from the mathematical protection provided by the encryption algorithm itself, which is considered unbreakable when a proper password is used. All sleep is is a special standby mode the CPU goes into to conserve power. The computer is still on during sleep, just saving power.

If a computer is sleeping and the encrypted drive is unlocked, an attacker could try to hack the computer and steal the encryption key. They may try a cold boot attack where they freeze and remove the memory modules. They may connect a debugging probe to the motherboard and hijack the CPU. If a computer is actually off, then they cannot do any of this. The only way they could access the drive contents is if your password is weak enough that they (or an automated program) could guess it. This is a property called data-at-rest security, which encryption provides. The data itself is only secure if it is at-rest on a powered down machine, not a machine which is sleeping.